# Using Caliburn.Micro with Mahapps MetroTabItem not loading View to ContentControl

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, caliburn.micro, mahapps.metro

I just started learning to use WPF as well as Caliburn.Micro(v3.2.0) and Mahapps(v2.0.0 a0105) and I am having an issue with trying to get a Mahapps MetroTabItem to display a View into a ContentControl box. The ContentControl was originally in a separate grid but from what I understand, that should be just fine. To test I moved it over and put it into the following: (Note that I set "Name" both as Name= and x:Name= and it didn't seem to make a difference.)

```
<!-- This is in AppView.xaml -->
<Grid.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.AnimatedTabControl.xaml" />
</Grid.Resources>
<TabControl Height="150"
                    Controls:TabControlHelper.Underlined="SelectedTabItem"
                    TabStripPlacement="Left" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
<Controls:MetroTabItem Header="EndPoints" Name="MenuEndPoint">
<ContentControl x:Name="ActiveItem" />
</Controls:MetroTabItem>
```

That still did not work either, though. If I replace the ContentControl with just a TextBlock, that works just fine, so I don't believe it is an issue with the tab setup, unless I just don't have that setup right. The actual EndpointView.xaml doesn't have much extra in it, just a TextBlock I put there so I could see it if it loaded.

My AppViewModel contains:

```
public class AppViewModel : Conductor<object>
{

    public void MenuEndPoint()
    {
        ActivateItem(new EndpointViewModel());
    }
```

My EndpointViewModel contains:

```
public class EndpointViewModel : Screen
{

}
```

I put the namespace of using myapp.Views into all of the ViewModels and then using myapp.ViewModels into the ViewModels just now to test to make sure it wasn't that, but there was no change either.

I watched https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=laPFq3Fhs8k from Tim Corey, as well as tried to find some other projects on GitHub that were using it as well in a similar manner, but could not spot anything different in how I was trying to use it. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks,
-MH

Answer (score 1):

To make it work, first you need to attach an event to your method.
Since you want it on mouse click, I believe you can use `PreviewMouseDown`.
To accomplish that, your `MetroTabItem` has to look like this:

```
 <Controls:MetroTabItem Header="EndPoints" Name="MenuEndPoint" cal:Message.Attach="[Event PreviewMouseDown]=[Action MenuEndPoints]" >
```

And rename your method to be plural as this:

```
public void MenuEndPoints()
    {
        ActivateItem(new EndpointViewModel());
    }
```

Comment: Hey there, I appreciate the reply. I ended up doing away with the actual tabs once I realized that I could still have the transition effect of the view loading into the content control and just made them buttons and then all worked just fine.